# How do I use a case statement to determine the from and where clauses in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, case

I have a long stored procedure that returns data on an item depending on the item selected.

I was able to build out the stored procedure the long way around using cases but I have to include a a lot of duplicate information in each case. WIth 11 different items to choose from I'd like to make the code as clean as possible.

There are only slight differences in the FROM and WHERE clauses but I am unable to figure out the right way to use Cases after the common INSERT and SELECT statement.

I have been searching around I understand that oracle is asking me for an appropriate THEN statement after the SELECT.

Is this just a syntax situation or is it fundamentally flawed.?

My working code for two cases is below. I've included comments on wher I'd like to put a case instead.

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
PROCEDURE Fetch_Data_By_Item     
(
inItem STRING,
RC1 IN OUT Sys_Refcursor
)AS

tRc1 SYS_REFCURSOR;

 BEGIN

       CASE
       WHEN inItem = 'ItemOne'
       THEN

       DELETE FROM TEMP_DATA;           ----Common to all procedures
       INSERT   INTO    TEMP_DATA
       (
          Item_Name,
          Item_OTher,
          Item_id,
          _code,
          _date
        )


     --Get all the ILists 

      WITH _LIST AS                 ----Common to all procedures
    ( 
           SELECT DISTINCT 
                           A.List_ as "_IList"
           FROM            Schema.VIEW_One             A
           INNER JOIN      SChema2.VIEW_Two    
           WHERE           A.SI_                = 'Y'   

    )

       --ItemOne


    (   SELECT           
              'Item_One' as "Item_Name",
              'ITem_One' as "Item_Other" ,
              S.Item_ID,
              T._CODE,
              S._DATE,                      ----Common to all procedures  

                        ----Case should start here    
       FROM   Schema.VIEW_ONE T, 
              SChema.VIEW_Two S
       WHERE  T.Item_id           =           S.Item_id
       AND    T.SI_               =           'Y' 
       AND    S.SI_                =          'Y'
       AND    T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
    )   

       );

       --Item 2

    WHEN inItem = 'ItemTwo'
        THEN

       DELETE FROM TEMP_DATA;
       INSERT   INTO    TEMP_DATA
       (
          Item_Name,
          Item_OTher,
          Item_id,
          _code,
          _date
       )


     --Get all the ILists

      WITH _LIST AS
    ( 

           SELECT DISTINCT 
                           A.List_ as "_IList"
           FROM            Schema.VIEW_One             A
           INNER JOIN      SChema2.VIEW_Two    
            WHERE           A.SI_               = 'Y'                    
       --Real Estate
    )

    (   SELECT           
              'Item_Two' as "Item_Name",
              'ITem_Two' as "Item_Other" ,
              S.Item_ID,
              T._CODE,
              S._DATE,                        

       FROM   Schema.VIEW_ONE   T, 
              SChema.VIEW_Two   S,
          Schema.VIEW_Three U
       WHERE  T.Item_id           =           S.Item_id
       AND    T.SI_               =           'Z' 
       AND    S.SI_               =           'Z'
       And    U.Id        =       '123'
       AND    T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
    )  ;

---9 other cases********

End Case;

OPEn RC1 for

SELECT

Item_Name,
Item_Other,
Item_Id,
code,
date

FROM TEMP_DATA;
END FETCH_DATA_BY_ITEM
```

*Revision*
As mentioned  have been trying a number of ways to achieve this result and so far this is the closest I can get. I just can't seem to figure out what's missing here. This is what I have at the moment, maybe can see something I'm missing?

```
    PROCEDURE Fetch_Data_By_Item
    (
    inItem STRING,
    RC1 IN OUT Sys_Refcursor
    )AS

   tRc1 SYS_REFCURSOR;

   BEGIN

   DELETE FROM TEMP_DATA;              ----Common to all procedures
   INSERT   INTO    TEMP_DATA
   (
      ....
   )
 --Get all the ILists 

  WITH _LIST AS                          ----Common to all procedures
( 
      ....
)

(   SELECT           
          S.Item_Name,
          S.Item_Other ,
          S.Item_ID,
          T._CODE,
          S._DATE,                         ----Common to all procedures  


   FROM   Schema.VIEW_ONE T, 
          Schema.VIEW_Two S,
          Schema.VIEW_Three U

   WHERE

   CASE inItem

   --ItemOne

   WHEN 'ItemOne'
   THEN

          T.Item_id     =           S.Item_id
   AND    T.SI_         =           'Y' 
   AND    S.SI_         =           'Y'
   AND    T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)

   --Item 2

   WHEN 'ItemTwo'
   THEN         

          T.Item_id     =           S.Item_id
   AND    T.SI_         =           'Z' 
   AND    S.SI_         =           'Z'
   And    U.Id          =          '123'
   AND    T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
   END
);

    ---9 other cases********

    OPEN RC1 for

    SELECT

    ....

    FROM TEMP_DATA;
    END FETCH_DATA_BY_ITEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a CASE for your WHERE clause as it currently is:

```
WHERE
(
   inItem = 'ItemOne'
   AND T.Item_id     =           S.Item_id
   AND    T.SI_         =           'Y' 
   AND    S.SI_         =           'Y'
   AND    T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
)
OR (
   inItem = 'ItemTwo'
   AND T.Item_id     =           S.Item_id
   AND    T.SI_         =           'Z' 
   AND    S.SI_         =           'Z'
   And    U.Id          =          '123'
   AND    T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
)
```

And depending upon your other options, this can be simplified:

```
WHERE
   T.Item_id     =           S.Item_id
   AND T.List_             NOT IN     (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
   AND (
      (
         inItem = 'ItemOne'
         AND    T.SI_         =           'Y' 
         AND    S.SI_         =           'Y'
      )
      OR (
         inItem = 'ItemTwo'
         AND    T.SI_         =           'Z' 
         AND    S.SI_         =           'Z'
         And    U.Id          =          '123'
      )
   )
```

If you have a "conditions" table of the form

```
inItem, T_SI_, S_SI_, U_Id
ItemOne, Y, Y, NULL
ItemTwo, Z, Z, 123
```

Then this gets a little simpler (I know you used implicit joins, which I recommend abandoning):

```
INNER JOIN conditions
    ON conditions.inItem = inItem
    AND (conditions.T_SI_ IS NULL OR conditions.T_SI_ = T.SI_)
    AND (conditions.S_SI_ IS NULL OR conditions.S_SI = S.SI_)
    AND (conditions.U_Id IS NULL OR conditions.U_Id = U.Id)
WHERE
   T.Item_id = S.Item_id -- This actually moves up into an INNER JOIN
   AND T.List_ NOT IN (SELECT _IList FROM  _LIST)
```

Logic tables are good for things which may occasionally change and often times can make for more readable code.  You have to be careful about going too meta, because this can make systems harder to maintain, but it can be a good strategy when used wisely.

Comment: This might be just the fix. I do have quite a number of little variations I left out for simplification but this looks promising.

Comment: @dee also note that it can sometimes be possible to drive complex literal conditions like this off a table, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I spent a couple of days working on the ideas you suggested. Unfortunately, I can not join the third view "Schema.VIEW_Three U" as it changes the result set for about half my items. Any idea if I can find some way to determine the FROM clause according to inItem?  Thanks.

Comment: @dee From your original example, it looks like U needs a CROSS JOIN (this would stop the INNER JOIN on conditions from working) - this would be a code smell to me, since in a given system I would rarely use a CROSS JOIN, if at all.  A table-driven approach can only work in cases where the logic is structured amenably to that approach.  In your code it's not really even clear what U provides except possibly multiplying the number of rows (which are then de-dupes with DISTINCT) when more than one satisfy the criteria.  No columns are even used from U.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Turns out the application this stored procedure is needed for requires me to build a more formal set-up without temp tables anyway. So I'm back to bulding a clunkier but more stable system anyway where each item will have it's own stored proc. I really apreciate your time and help, I learned a lot through this.

Answer (score 0):

To use different froms and wheres you need to use dynamic sql. You can do this with `execute immediate`. For example:

```
set serveroutput on size 10000
declare
  vtest  varchar2(1);
begin
  execute immediate 'select ''X'' from dual' into vtest;
  dbms_output.put_line(vtest);
end;
```

So you can create a variable to store your sql, and use the case to full your variable.

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)